# Find the weird sequence

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a weird sequence from my array. I've sorted it and then I was trying to get the weird sequence so that I could remove it and my array will work in sequence again. Assuming I've sorted elements in increasing order. It is not working on input 6 7 8 10 inputs are given in comments. For all the inputs in comments, I need output 10, 12, 42 for each line.

```
//6 7 8 10
//12 156 157 158 159 160 161 162
//42 45 46 47 48
        int temp=a[0];
        for(int j=0; j<s-1; j++)
        {
            if(a[j+1]!=a[j]+1)          
            {
                temp=a[j];

            }

        }
        System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: I think you are being downvoted because we don't know what a weird sequence is. And your code won't compile.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: @Muhammad Raza , I don't know Why you are being downvoted..
I understood your question..,So first tell me "are you getting right answer for last two"?

Answer (score 0):

*I think you should be more clear while asking a question on SO* .

Seems like you are trying to solve some problem on some Coding Platform and they have named their problem like *"Weird sequence"*

Anyways , I understood your question ,

By *weird sequence* you mean the one number *which is not in sequence* like others numbers.

So for

```
6 7 8 10
```

o/p should be 10

```
12 156 157 158 159 160 161 162
```

o/p should be 12

```
42 45 46 47 48
```

o/p 42

So *here is the approach* I would suggest,

it is just `O(n)`

Do *one iteration*

find the common difference

eg for input `6,7,8,10` it is

```
7-6 =1

8-7 =1

10-8 =2
```

hence 10 is culprit

i.e.
keep track of what difference you are getting in some variable ,as soon as you get different number for difference

you get to know that either current or previous number is the required answer